# Unable to find docker blue whale icon in windows 10 system tray

Tags: docker

I'm not able to find the docker blue whale icon in system tray.I have tried uninstalling and installing docker but no luck.

Here is my docker information.I tried the version 19.03.1 as well but same issue.I want to change some settings and as per documentation there should be a icon in system tray for docker.

```
Client:
 Version:           18.09.3
 API version:       1.39
 Go version:        go1.12
 Git commit:        774a1f4eee
 Built:             Mon Mar  4 10:36:44 2019
 OS/Arch:           windows/amd64
 Experimental:      false

Server: Docker Engine - Community
 Engine:
  Version:          19.03.5
  API version:      1.40 (minimum version 1.12)
  Go version:       go1.12.12
  Git commit:       633a0ea838
  Built:            Wed Nov 13 07:28:45 2019
  OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
  Experimental:     false
 containerd:
  Version:          v1.2.10
  GitCommit:        b34a5c8af56e510852c35414db4c1f4fa6172339
 runc:
  Version:          1.0.0-rc8+dev
  GitCommit:        3e425f80a8c931f88e6d94a8c831b9d5aa481657
 docker-init:
  Version:          0.18.0
  GitCommit:        fec3683
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the application docker desktop which is a Graphical User Interface and you are installing the software to run the containers

https://hub.docker.com/editions/community/docker-ce-desktop-windows